# Aligning buttons with a row in a table using css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to develop a table that can be used to edit database information (for non-database users).  Here's what I have (for html):

```
<table id="myTable" cellspacing='0'>
    <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th></tr>
    <tr id='1'><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>2</td>
    <td style=" table-layout:fixed">
     <div style="width:0px;overflow:visible;position:relative">
        <a style="display:block;position:relative;left:20px">-</a>
     </div>
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr id='2' class='even'><td>3</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr id='3'><td>13</td><td>21</td><td>34</td></tr>
    <tr id='4' class='even'><td>55</td><td>89</td><td>144</td></tr>
    <tr id='5'><td>233</td><td>377</td><td>610</td></tr>
</table>
<input class="addRow" type="button" value="+">
</table>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
table {
    background: #E0F5F9;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #1C9CBC;  
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

table th {
    padding:4px 10px;
    background: #A8A8A8;
}

table td {
    background:#fff;
    padding:2px 10px 4px 10px;
}

div.editableTable {
    display: inline;
}

input.addRow {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: solid 2px #1C9CBC;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: #A8A8A8;

}

table tr.even td {background:#98E6F9}
table tr td {
    background: #E0F5F9;
}

table tr.editing td {
    background: #FF0000;
}

table tr.selectedEven td {
    background: #98E6F9;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
}

table tr.selectedEven td:first-child {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
}

table tr.selectedEven td:last-child {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
}

table tr.selectedEven td:last-child {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
}

table tr.selected td {
    /* background: #E0F5F9; */
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
}

table tr.selected td:first-child {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
}

table tr.selected td:last-child {
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
}

table tr.selected td:last-child {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #03C100;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px
}
```

And, here's what it looks like:
[image: Table design, second try]

This is fine, except that the delete button on the right side is a little off from the row.  This means that once we add ~13 or 14 rows, the delete button is way off from the row that it's going to be deleting.  Thus, it's unclear to the user exactly which row will be removed when they hit remove.

I'd like to find some method that will allow me to align a button (or, in this case, a few buttons) with the row of the table in question, using CSS.  Is this possible? I tried initially (without success) to do this without a second table, but that led me to the current situation, where I have a table for alignment purposes only on the right of the table that actually contains the data.

The big problem I'm faced with is that I can't seem to figure out how to align something with a row in a table. I could probably do it with jQuery, but this seems like taking a hammer to a screw. I'll admit I'm not as experienced at CSS as I am at programming, and so I usually tend to look to the programming answer. Can someone help me figure out how to have these buttons aligned correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: What results are yielded when you don't use 2 tables? By the way using tables for "alignment" = using tables for layout = very bad practise.

Comment: @myles gray: I agree completely about the alignment/layout thing.  It's just that I couldn't get it to work another way (or at least that I can find). What I tried to do ended up displaying the button to the left of the table, above it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try placing the button inside the last `<td>` in the row and then float it to the right and provide a large enough negative right margin to get it outside the table; you'll also need a positive right margin on the table to make sure there is space for the button.

For example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>kdsjfkdsl fds</td>
            <td><span class="killer">X</span>Appropriately architect 24/365 internal or "organic" sources after fully tested portals. Monotonectally leverage existing an expanded array of action items before resource maximizing growth strategies. Proactively drive orthogonal ROI before sustainable relationships.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2193485798435</td>
            <td><span class="killer">X</span>Enthusiastically deploy team building data with e-business internal or "organic" sources. Enthusiastically negotiate diverse models for transparent communities. Intrinsicly disseminate just in time markets before vertical paradigms. Authoritatively brand performance based web-readiness for error-free growth strategies. Energistically empower customer directed markets with quality data. Distinctively productivate backward-compatible potentialities before prospective technology.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And a bit of CSS (with coloring to make it clear where everything is):

```
table {
    margin-right: 2em;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
span.killer {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -1.5em;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RE8rK/

I picked the margins out of the air to illustrate the effect, I'll leave computing the proper values up to you.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I needed. Thanks, I appreciate it. Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.

Comment: @jwir3: No worries, as long as you got things sorted out. Negative margins are a great trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript but it can't be done reliably with CSS (unless you want to restrict cell height). I'd recommend just putting the button in the same row in the original table (ie, add another column) and removing styles from that column. You might have to give up the rounded corners though but your colors and borders can be preserved.

EDIT: The code below might let you keep your rounded corners.

```
<tr>
  <td>data</td>
  <td>data</td>
  <td style="width:1px">
     <div style="width:1px;overflow:visible;position:relative">
        <a style="display:block;position:relative;left:20px">-</a>
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td:last-child, table th:last-child {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hm, yeah, I tried that. I'd like to avoid giving up the rounded corners (they look nice, heh). I will try again, as the first time, I wasn't able to get the styles to accurately disable as I wanted.

Comment: You might be able to keep the rounded corners if you make the final column 1px width with an overflow:visible and then relative position the button (ie, it's structurally inside the row but is rendered outside it). The catch is tables often behave badly when you try messing with cell overflows like this. Try it though. I've had success in the past by putting a div inside the cell and overflowing the div instead.

Comment: Ok, so this works, but I can't seem to get it to remove the styles on the table cell and still show the button. I tried adding a display: none; to the table cell, but of course, this removes all of the children as well. If I try to reset the style, the problem is that it doesn't work on rows that don't have the button.

Comment: You might have to post your revised CSS but you should be able to make this work by making the cell very narrow (0 or 1px) and using the same colors as the row background on the last cell. You may need to set `table-layout:fixed` on the table to control the layout so accurately or else the table will keep expanding the last cell to fit your button.

Comment: Ok, I posted an example that has the updated CSS and HTML. Actually, this is a standalone example (not the one I'm actually using in the script for the image), so you should be able to put it into a browser and have it work as a standalone.

Comment: I also uploaded a new image which shows what I am seeing in Firefox.

Comment: You didn't follow my advice. Look at the CSS I posted above and try again. Also add another TH to your header and empty TD's to each row that doesn't need the button. Your columns are uneven.

Comment: @Spliff: No disrespect meant. I perhaps didn't understand what you meant. I wasn't sure where to put the table-layout: fixed, and I tried to place it in the td and table element selector CSS, but neither seemed to have an effect, so I removed it. I will repost with the new CSS.