# How to add a button next to a table row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a table. The last row is an input field where the user can add records. What I want is an "add"-button next to that row which the user clicks to store the new data. Visually the button is going to be outside the table, to the right.

I don't know how to do this and need some guidance. How do I add this kind of button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last cell of the last row put a `<div>` with `position:relative` and inside that div put your button with `position:absolute` and move the button outside the table with `right: -width_of_the_button`. And you would add new rows before the last row in the table, so that the button is always in the last row

You need that `<div>` because some browsers (Firefox) don't respect `position:relative` on table cells and rows.

Comment: +1 Could add the new row to the bottom of the table and just move the div to the last cell in the last row each time a row is added.

Comment: Moving the button around is an extraneous DOM manipulation, which is costly performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

add a blank set of tds for all the other rows and in the last row you have the add button. How does that sound?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the table inside the first column of another two column table, then add the button to the second column and align it vertically to the bottom.

Here's a jsfiddle for the table method - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/zFEQT/1/

This question deals with lining up buttons to table rows via css -

[Aligning buttons with a row in a table using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981888/aligning-buttons-with-a-row-in-a-table-using-css)